# My code is showing an error "Check the render method of `Products`". How can I do to fix that?

Tags: reactjs

I run the dev but in console, there's an error saying "Check the render method of `Products`". This is my App.

App.jsx
[image: App.jsx]

I want Products to be shown but it doesn't appear. This is my Products.

Product.jsx
[image: Products.jsx]

Comment: you can add more detail for your problem,through the image from you post ,can not get the error you get

Comment: Does the error say anything else? Also you can remove `products`, seems like a big array, from the `Products` component and move it outside so it will not get redefined.

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is not true. use this :

```
{products.map((product) => (
   <h1 key={product.id}>{product.title}</h1>
))}
```

Comment: i added key but still showing the error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If your error is the same as the image above, try using key in each child (Product Element) and it's going to work! Like as follow:

```
products.map((product,index) => <h1 key={index}>{product.title}</h1>))
```

To use index as a key is not appreciated in react so use id of product as a key. [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)